# how to position link in the center of the width and the height?

Tags: html, css

I made this : [jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/centerwow/p9S5W/25/show)

I have the line :

`<div id="footer">
    <h1><a class="link" href="http://www.centerwow.com">mysite</a></h1>
</div>`

​
How can I center the link **mysite** in the `div footer` on the center. width and height it Should be under about(menu).
I try to put position absolute and relative and somehow  I destroyed something else.
thanks for any help.

my code:

```
body {
    background: #CC3366 url(images/temp.png) center 130px no-repeat ;
    overflow:hidden;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 32px;
    }
#container { 
    width: 1000px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    height: 450px;
    margin: 0 auto;
 }

#all_pages {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 3000px;
    }
.page {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 400px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
    }    
.page img {
    margin-top: 50px;
    }
#menu {
    background: #000;
    }
#menu ul { 
    list-style: none;
    width: 457px;
    height: 35px;
    margin:auto;
    }
#menu ul li {
    float: left;
    color: #888;
    width: 150px;
    line-height: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
.active {
    color: #fff !important;
    }
h1 a {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;

}
#footer a{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:80px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#footer{
    position:relative;
    background: #CC3366;
    width:100%;
    height:1000px;

}​

<h1><a class="link" style="position:absolute; left:30px; top:30px;" href="http://www.centerwow.com">portfolio</a></h1>
<div id="container">

    <div id="all_pages">

        <div class="page">
            <h1>Home Page</h1>
            <img src="images/home.png" width="300">
        </div> <!-- page1 -->
        <div class="page">
            <h1>About Us Page</h1>
            <img src="images/about.png" width="300">
        </div> <!-- page2 --> 
        <div class="page">
            <h1>Contact Us Page</h1>
            <img src="images/contact.png" width="300">
        </div> <!-- page2 --> 

    </div> <!-- #all_pages -->

</div> <!-- #container -->

<div id="menu">
<ul>
    <li id="1" class="link CC3366 active">Home</li>
    <li id="2" class="link 33FF66">About</li>
    <li id="3" class="link FFFF33">Contact Us</li>
</ul>
</div> <!-- #menu -->
<div id="footer">
    <h1><a class="link" href="http://www.centerwow.com">mysite</a></h1>
</div>
​
```

Comment: did you try with h1 {text-align:center} ?

Comment: yes it help to add thx  `h1 {text-align:center} `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is something like [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BZybV/1/) what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
position :relative 
top:50% ;
Left:50%;
```

works or not?